# affect defined function to every new created element (select element)

Tags: javascript

In my web site I have select tag, every time that select is changed new select element is created, I need to affect to it the same on change function, so I declared a function called par ex : select_function(params1,params2,...) but I didn't know how to set it to every new element created, if I try simply this :`select.on change=select_change(params1,params2,...);`  the function will be  executed when the script is loaded such that function will return result. So any help ...

Code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var j=1;
    var table= document.getElementById('bilan');
    var select=document.getElementById('bilan_'+j);
    select.onchange=select_change(j,bilan_array,table,select);
});

function select_change(j,bilan_array,table){
    select_list=document.createElement('select');
    select_list.id='bilan_'+j;
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    select_list.appendChild(option);
    for(var k=0;k<bilan_array.length;k++){
        option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = bilan_array[k][0];
        option.text = bilan_array[k][3];
        select_list.appendChild(option);

        select_list.onchange=select_change(j,bilan_array,table,select);
    }
```

this code is simplfied because the function is too long ...

Comment: show whole code please

Comment: Do you mean that if the new select is changed then it also generates another new select?

Comment: yes, and the generated select must handle the same function when changed

Comment: You need to set it equal to an anonymous function that calls your function with parameters.

Comment: so smart :p thanxs a lot @James Sutherland :)